# Repeat/duplicate a given numpy array ten times

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have a numpy `array` of shape, (320, 320, 3). I want to repeat/duplicate this data 10 times, and want to get new array of shape (*10*, 320, 320, 3).

How to do it?

```
array = np.ones((320, 320, 3))
print (array.shape)
(320, 320, 3)
```

I tried as:

```
res = np.tile(array, 10)
print (res.shape)

(320, 320, 30).
```

But I want `shape` of,

```
(10, 320, 320, 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) -

```
np.broadcast_to(a,(10,)+a.shape).copy() # a is input array
```

If we are okay with a view instead, skip `.copy()` for a virtually free runtime and zero memory overhead.

We can also use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) -

```
np.repeat(a[None],10,axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.resize`, which will tile if the new size is larger than the old one:

```
array = np.ones((320, 320, 3))

new_array = np.resize(array, (10, *array.shape))
print(new_array.shape)
# (10, 320, 320, 3)
```

From [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html):

> `numpy.resize(a, new_shape)`: If the new array is larger than the original array, then the new array is filled with repeated copies of a.

Answer (score 1):

```
res = np.tile(array, (10,1,1,1))
print (res.shape)
```